# Minimization of The Blind Deconvolution Functional

Tags: optimization, pde

I want to minimize the functional of the Blind Deconvolution model as given in: [Total Variation Blind Deconvolution by Chan and Wong](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/661187).

Their model is given by:

$$ z = h \ast u + \eta $$

Where $ \ast $ is the convolution operator, $ h $ is the blurring kernel, $ u $ is the sharp noiseless image and $ \eta $ is additive white gaussian noise (AWGN).

The functional to be minimized is given by (Assuming the Blurring Kernel is known):

$$ \underset{u}{\min} f \left( u \right ) = \underset{u}{\min} \left \{ \frac{1}{2} {\left \| h \ast u - z \right \|}^{2}_{L_{2}} + \alpha \int \left | \nabla u \right | dx dy \right \} $$

Where $ \alpha $ is the smoothing term.

Yet, in Blind Deconvolution the Kernel isn't known and the minimization functional is given by:

$$ \underset{u}{\min} f \left( u \right ) = \underset{u}{\min} \left \{ \frac{1}{2} {\left \| h \ast u - z \right \|}^{2}_{L_{2}} + {\alpha}_{1} \int \left | \nabla u \right | dx dy + {\alpha}_{2} \int \left | \nabla h \right | dx dy \right \} $$

Now, The Euler Lagrange equations I calculated and given in the article are:

$$\begin{align} \frac{\delta L}{\delta h} & = \left ( u \ast h - z \right ) \ast u \left( -x, -y \right ) - {\alpha}_{2} \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{\nabla h}{\left | \nabla h \right |} \right) \\ \frac{\delta L}{\delta u} & = \left ( u \ast h - z \right ) \ast h \left( -x, -y \right ) - {\alpha}_{1} \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{\nabla u}{\left | \nabla u \right |} \right) \end{align}$$

What I'm not sure about is how can I use it to solve the problem.
At the article they suggest the alternating method, namely once solve for $ h $ and then for $ u $.

Yet I don't see how to write in in MATLAB code (Or any other pseudo code).
It should be some kind of a Gradient Descent step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blind deconvolution should be a minimization on both $u$ and $h$:

$$ \underset{u,h}{\min} f \left( u, h \right ) = \underset{u,h}{\min} \left \{ \frac{1}{2} {\left \| h \ast u - z \right \|}^{2}_{L_{2}} + {\alpha}_{1} \int \left | \nabla u \right | dx dy + {\alpha}_{2} \int \left | \nabla h \right | dx dy \right \} $$

The standard way to do this is to alternately hold one variable fixed and minimize on the other, ie.

\begin{cases} 
      u^{k+1} = \underset{u}{\text{argmin}} f(u,h^k) \\
      h^{k+1} = \underset{h}{\text{argmin}} f(u^k,h) \\
\end{cases}

Back when Chan and Wong wrote their paper the way to minimize total variation was to write out the Euler-Lagrange equations which leads to those complicated and slow to solve PDEs. Now there are faster and easier ways to solve each of those subproblems (eg Split-Bregman) which will simplify things for you.

A bit of searching led to me to this 2014 paper: http://www.cvg.unibe.ch/dperrone/tvdb/ which has more information as well as publicly-available MATLAB code. I'm not familiar with their work but it's not easy to publish in CVPR so it's probably worth a look...

Comment: Thank You for your answer. 2 Questions: 1. What if I want to implement the straight way, using Gradient Descent, I don't understand how create the corrects dimensions of the signals (At least in the iteration solving for the Blur Kernel). 2. Can I use MATLAB's `fminunc` function for the minimization? Thank You.

Comment: Since you have a TV-penalty on h gradient descent won't work since the TV functional is not differentiable. There is some research on smoothing out the TV-term using a parameter (usually called epsilon) that goes under a square root somewhere but the newer Bregman stuff is easier to implement. I don't know how fminunc works but I suspect it won't be a good choice for this difficult problem. After a first pass over the linked CVPR paper I suggest taking a look at their research and code.

Comment: Hi, I looked at their paper and they do use Gradient Descent (Am I wrong?). They use it alternatively (Holding the Kernel, calculating the Image and vice versa).

Comment: Huh, yeah I see it now in alg. 1. In the following paragraph they remark that they only do one iteration - I don't know how that changes things. Also, they have alpha_2 = 0 which simplifies things a bit. In any event, computing the div*(nabla/|nabla|) (the curvature of a level curve) isn't easy. The linked paper has a function gradTVcc(f,epsilon) in their code that handles the computation.